# Javascript set value of class & hidden input in nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span class "checkbox" and an attribute "value" associated with a hidden input field, both of which are contained within nested divs.

By default the checkbox is unchecked but I would like to change the span class to "checkbox active" and the input value to "1" so that it is checked and rendered to reflect that change.

This code is generated by a Wordpress plugin and there are no ids.

What's the best method to set these two attributes?

```
<div class="field field-news_item" data-type="true_false" data-name="news_item" data-validator="">
     <div class="cfs_true_false ready">
        <span class="checkbox"></span>
        <span>Is this a news item?</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="cfs[input][6][value]" class="true_false" value="0">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many such constructs are there on the page? Do you want to change all of those?

Comment: use class attribute.

Comment: There is only one construct of this type on the page so it's limited to a single instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement.Why dont you set like this ??

```
$(document).ready(myfunc);

function myfunc()
{
$('.checkbox').addClass('checked');
  $('.true_false').val('1'); 


}

if($('.checkbox').hasClass('checked'))
{
alert($('.true_false').val());
}
```

Click on the demo below to see that *value 1 is getting set* and *checked class is getting set*.
**You can do this on click of a button or checking a checkbox.**

Click [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhfmvz8b/)

Comment: This is actually a very simple solution and will work perfectly in my context. For WP, note that you can use a jQuery noConflict wrapper.

I was originally expecting a solution using a querySelector or the DOM so if someone is feeling ambitious I'm sure that would be helpful as well. Per @Ajay is the best option for this route to use the class as a reference point?

Comment: @mrickan yes just to be on safer side you can use   $.noConflict();   ..And you can thumbs up the answer if you like

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Also for demo purpose, I have kept input as `text` instead of `hidden`.

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meqjs7ux/)

```js
(function(){
 $(".checkbox").on("click",function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("checked");
        var val = 0;
        val = $(this).hasClass("checked")?1:0;
        $(this).parent().find(".true_false").val(val);
    });
})()
```

```css
.checked{
    background: blue!important;
}

.checkbox{
    width:20px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field field-news_item" data-type="true_false" data-name="news_item" data-validator="">
     <div class="cfs_true_false ready">
        <span class="checkbox"></span>
         <span>Is this a news item?</span>
        <input type="text" name="cfs[input][6][value]" class="true_false" value="0">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field field-news_item" data-type="true_false" data-name="news_item" data-validator="">
     <div class="cfs_true_false ready">
        <span class="checkbox"></span>
        <span>Is this a news item?</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> 
        <input type="text" name="cfs[input][6][value]" class="true_false" value="0">
     </div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
var checkboxValue = $(this).is(':checked');
if(checkboxValue == true){
 $(".true_false").val('1');
 alert('1');
    }else{
    $(".true_false").val('0');
     alert('0');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> 
        <input type="text" name="cfs[input][6][value]" class="true_false" value="0">

this two i have added only for testing that value has been changed when you click on check box